# What is the fractional frequency stability of a thermal damped harmonic oscillator?

Tags: thermodynamics, harmonic-oscillator, stability, noise, fluctuation-dissipation

Suppose I have a lightly driven (classical) damped harmonic oscillator at temperature $T$. Suppose $\omega$ and $Q$ are specified as well as the mean energy $\bar{E}$ in the oscillator due to the driving/dissipation equilibrium. What will be the fractional frequency stability of this oscillator? What is the formalism to treat this problem?

Comment: I think you might need to specify the phase noise. I am not sure if you have all the necessary information in the problem statement.   https://thesis.library.caltech.edu/5255/8/08-Chapter2_PhaseNoise.pdf seems to be an introduction. If the noise is thermal, then maybe you are obtaining it from the spectral density. If the noise is of some other type the Allen variance would be different.

Comment: Yes, thermal noise. Will check the reference.

Answer (score 1):

The by-now ancient work/publication but also time-tested by billions of well-designed oscillators and probably will answer your question is Leeson: A Simple Model of Feedback Oscillator Noise Spectrum, Proc. IEEE, 1966 pp329-330.